# Como descobrir a maior sequência entre dois vetores?

Tags: java, array, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho dois vetores, um com 10 elementos e outro com 5 elementos. Preciso checar quantos desse elementos estão em sequência. Por exemplo:

basicamente estou fazendo um programa que sorteia 10 numeros aleatorios.
eu peço pro usuario entrar com cinco numeros.
tenho que verificar quantos numeros digitados peloo usuario correspondem aos numeros dentro da array entre os 10 numeros digitados.

esse programa é como se fosse um jogo de loteria, sao sorteados 10 numeros e o usuario entra com 5 numeros.

Eu quero saber se a sequencia de numeros digitados pelo usuario estão dentro do vetor e se algum deles estao na mesma sequencia digitada.
ex.
winnerNum = [23 56 67 ****06 43 22**** 59 24 90 66]
UserNumb = [01 ***06 43 22*** 89]

numeros 06, 43, 22, estao dentro do vetor da loteria e estao na mesma sequencia.
sequecia = 3.

Estou há algumas horas tentando verificar qual é a maior sequência entre eles, porém não consigo.

Não posso usar nenhum tipo específico de método, pois tenho que usar apenas o que foi ensinado em aula, que seria apenas `while`, `for`, `if`... essas coisas mais básicas.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você esta buscando a subsequência crescente máxima. Da uma olhada nesse exemplo: https://github.com/arturmbrasil/subsequencia_crescente_maxima/blob/master/subsequencia_crescente_maxima.py

Comment: coloque um exemplo do resultado esperado, pq a pergunta está consfusa... sequencia quer dizer necessariamente numeros sequeciais, por exemplo "1,2,3"? ou qual o intervalo (2 em 2, etc)? pq usar 2 arrays? está confuso, explique melhor e mostre um exemplo do resultado esperado

Comment: realmente estava cofunso haha, eu tinha digitado isso de madrugada após umas 10 hrs de codificação, nao era eu que estava digitando, era meu cansaço kk, espero q melhore o entendimento.